# How to not let chat pop up appear after user close it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**

I've Been working on this for quite sometime now and my goal is to not let chat pop-up to appear after user closes the chat box and when i refresh the page it should not appear. Any fixes would be appreciated. I am thinking sessionStorage should be the best solution to this problem. However what would be the best way to check if page if loaded and once it loaded it should go according the sessionsStorage as in keep the same key/value pairs just so when i refresh the page chat-pop up will not appear

```
    <!--javascript-->
    var myTimer = 0;
    var milliseconds = 4000;
    // for page on load
    $(window).on('load', function() {
      myTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".chat-popup").show();
          if (typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined') {
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $("button").click(function() {
                sessionStorage.setItem("myTimer", "true");
                $('#myForm').hide('slow');    
              })
            });
            //console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('myTimer'));
          }
        })
      }, milliseconds);
      //window.clearTimeout(myTimer);
    });
    <!--css-->body {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    /* Button used to open the chat form - fixed at the bottom of the page */
    .open-button {
      display: none;
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px 20px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      opacity: 0.8;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 23px;
      right: 28px;
      width: 280px;
    }
    /* The popup chat - hidden by default */
    .chat-popup {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 15px;
      border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
      z-index: 9;
    }
    /* Add styles to the form container */
    .form-container {
      max-width: 300px;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: white;
    }
    /* Full-width textarea */
    .form-container textarea {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 15px;
      margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
      border: none;
      background: #f1f1f1;
      resize: none;
      min-height: 200px;
    }
    /* When the textarea gets focus, do something */
    .form-container textarea:focus {
      background-color: #ddd;
      outline: none;
    }
    /* Set a style for the submit/send button */
    .form-container .btn {
      background-color: orangered;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px 20px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      opacity: 0.8;
    }
    /* Add a red background color to the cancel button */
    .form-container .cancel {
      background-color: purple;
      position: absolute;
      left: 260px;
      top: 0;
      width: 2rem;
    }
    /* Add some hover effects to buttons */
    .form-container .btn:hover,
    .open-button:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--html language-->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <h2>Popup Chat box</h2>
      <p>On Page load pop-up chat will appear after 4000 milliseconds.</p>
      <button class="open-button">Chat</button>
      <div class="chat-popup" id="myForm">
        <form action="/#" class="form-container">
          <h1>Chat</h1>
          <label for="msg"><b>Message</b></label>
          <textarea placeholder="Type message.." name="msg" required></textarea>
          <button type="submit" class="btn">Send</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn cancel">&times;</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!--jquery cdn-->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
      <!--chat js-->
      <script src="chat.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>




            

            
            <!--js-->
            
            
        
        `var myTimer = 0;
            var milliseconds = 4000;
            // for page on load
            $(window).on('load', function() {
                myTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $(".chat-popup").show();
                        if (typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined') {
                            $(document).ready(function() {
                                $("button").click(function() {
                                    sessionStorage.setItem("myTimer", "true");
                                    $('#myForm').hide('slow');
                                    console.log('cancel clicked');
                                })
                            });
                            console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('myTimer'));
                        }
        
                    })
                }, milliseconds);
                //window.clearTimeout(myTimer);
        
            });
        
        
       ` 
            body {
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }
        
            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
        
        
        
            .open-button {
                display: none;
                background-color: #555;
                color: white;
                padding: 16px 20px;
                border: none;
                cursor: pointer;
                opacity: 0.8;
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 23px;
                right: 28px;
                width: 280px;
            }
        
        
        
        
            .chat-popup {
                display: none;
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
                right: 15px;
                border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
                z-index: 9;
            }
        
        
        
        
            .form-container {
                max-width: 300px;
                padding: 10px;
                background-color: white;
            }
        
        
        
        
            .form-container textarea {
                width: 100%;
                padding: 15px;
                margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
                border: none;
                background: #f1f1f1;
                resize: none;
                min-height: 200px;
            }
        
        
        
        
            .form-container textarea:focus {
                background-color: #ddd;
                outline: none;
            }
        
        
        
        
            .form-container .btn {
                background-color: orangered;
                color: white;
                padding: 16px 20px;
                border: none;
                cursor: pointer;
                width: 100%;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                opacity: 0.8;
            }
        
        
        
        
            .form-container .cancel {
                background-color: purple;
                position: absolute;
                left: 260px;
                top: 0;
                width: 2rem;
            }
        
        
        
            .form-container .btn:hover,
            .open-button:hover {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        `
        
        
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
        
            <head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
            </head>
        
            <body>
        
                <h2>Popup Chat Window</h2>
                <p>On Page load pop-up chat will appear after 4000 milliseconds.</p>
        
        
                <button class="open-button">Chat</button>
        
                <div class="chat-popup" id="myForm">
                    <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container">
                        <h1>Chat</h1>
        
                        <label for="msg"><b>Message</b></label>
                        <textarea placeholder="Type message.." name="msg" required></textarea>
        
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Send</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn cancel">&times;</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
        
                <!--jquery cdn-->
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
                <!--chat js-->
                <script src="chat.js"></script>
        
            </body>
        
            </html>
    `
            
            




            Don't want chat pop-up to appear after user closes the chat box and when i refresh the page it should not appear. Any fixes would be appreciated.
```

**

Comment: Hi, @appdesigns.  I'd really recommend some concrete code as part of your question.  There are millions of different implementations for these sorts of things.  We can't help if we can't see how your pop-up is currently built.

Comment: Hey, welcome here. You should have a look on [mcve].

Comment: speaking generally using javascript you should register a cookie maybe that holds that value `popup_was_closed_cookie_dont_show_it` and based on it show popup or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create some variable in localStorage to check if user has closed it previously and then on every window load event show it if it hasnt been closed or dont show it if it has been closed. Of course to keep preventing popping it up while loading i would initialy make it invisible.

Comment: I can not initially make it invisible. The goal is to make it visible after 10 seconds user stays on the website. When user close the chat-pop, it should not appear. In so doing, i used sessionStorage and yet not getting expected output

Comment: @appdesigns I dont know much of jquery but i think you're displaying it before checking if "session storage" item has been set. You should firstly check if it has been set and then if not so display it after this "10 seconds" elapsed.

Comment: @appdesigns but if you're asking about just hiding it after user clicks on "x" just add listener to this "x" button "onClick" and after user clicks on it add style to whole pop up with "display: none". In vanila js you would just "document.querySelector('').style.display = 'none'" and i dont remember how it was in jQuery but for sure you find answer just googling it

Comment: I am already using that approach $('#myForm').css("display", "none");...But my goal is once user clicks to close chat-pop and then refreshes the page; chat pop-up should not appear again after 10 seconds.

Comment: if (localStorage.getItem("hasBeenClosed") === null) {
  setTimeout(...);
}

Do everything in this setTimeout() i mean add event listener on button and of course show it then when user clicks on it just "localStorage.setItem("hasBeenClosed", true);
That should do the job ;)

Comment: Thanks Much  @snoh66 I am using sessionStorage so all I did was to change localStorage to sessionStorage and it is working for me now. What I did first was to check if getItem is null and then when user clicks to close chatbox; setItem then used my jquery to display none when user click to close chatbox.